# I have an issue with my CodeIgniter site in which i'm facing the indexing issue

Tags: php, api, indexing, codeigniter-3

I have an issue with my CodeIgniter site in which I'm facing  the indexing issue how can i implement google search console API in  to my site so my site index fast.

I already install code from github and also install api key

Comment: For Indexing you need to add index in database

Comment: For index you  need to make proper meta and canonical tags in head section, plus make the URL easy to read make it slug-like WordPress